# Can multiple updates in one transaction cause deadlock?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Mysql DB is our application database. In my java code, I have multiple updates for one transaction.

```
t = session.beginTransaction();
q1.executeUpdate();
q2.executeUpdate();
q3.executeUpdate();
t.commit();
```

Note q1 and q3 update the same table q1 is like

`update table1 set col0 = 'A' where id = 'myId'`

and q3 is

`update table1 set col0 = 'B' where col0 = 'C'`.

Will this cause deadlock trouble? If it is, will I be able to see a "deadlock" exception in the script (I am using hibernate to achieve above function). Thanks in advance.